# bootstrap no me compila la palleta de colores extendida

Tags: sass, scss, bootstrap-5

estoy intentando compilar el siguiente archivo sass para Bootstrap:

```
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";

$custom-colors: (
        "rc-red": #DA291C,
        "rc-wine": #A50034,
        "rc-blue": #002554,
        "rc-gold": #FFB200,
        "rc-silver": #808080,
        "rc-skyblue": #00B0F0,
        "aliceblue": #f0f8ff,
        "antiquewhite": #faebd7,
        "aqua": #00ffff,
        "aquamarine": #7fffd4,
        "azure": #f0ffff,
        "beige": #f5f5dc,
        "bisque": #ffe4c4,
        "blanchedalmond": #ffebcd,
        "blueviolet": #8a2be2,
        "brown": #a52a2a,
        "burlywood": #deb887,
        "cadetblue": #5f9ea0,
        "chartreuse": #7fff00,
        "chocolate": #d2691e,
        "coral": #ff7f50,
        "cornflowerblue": #6495ed,
        "cornsilk": #fff8dc,
        "crimson": #dc143c,
        "darkblue": #00008b,
        "darkcyan": #008b8b,
        "darkgoldenrod": #b8860b,
        "darkgray": #a9a9a9,
        "darkgreen": #006400,
        "darkgrey": #a9a9a9,
        "darkkhaki": #bdb76b,
        "darkmagenta": #8b008b,
        "darkolivegreen": #556b2f,
        "darkorange": #ff8c00,
        "darkorchid": #9932cc,
        "darkred": #8b0000,
        "darksalmon": #e9967a,
        "darkseagreen": #8fbc8f,
        "darkslateblue": #483d8b,
        "darkslategray": #2f4f4f,
        "darkslategrey": #2f4f4f,
        "darkturquoise": #00ced1,
        "darkviolet": #9400d3,
        "deeppink": #ff1493,
        "deepskyblue": #00bfff,
        "dimgray": #696969,
        "dimgrey": #696969,
        "dodgerblue": #1e90ff,
        "firebrick": #b22222,
        "floralwhite": #fffaf0,
        "forestgreen": #228b22,
        "fuchsia": #ff00ff,
        "gainsboro": #dcdcdc,
        "ghostwhite": #f8f8ff,
        "gold": #ffd700,
        "goldenrod": #daa520,
        "greenyellow": #adff2f,
        "grey": #808080,
        "honeydew": #f0fff0,
        "hotpink": #ff69b4,
        "indianred": #cd5c5c,
        "ivory": #fffff0,
        "khaki": #f0e68c,
        "lavender": #e6e6fa,
        "lavenderblush": #fff0f5,
        "lawngreen": #7cfc00,
        "lemonchiffon": #fffacd,
        "lightblue": #add8e6,
        "lightcoral": #f08080,
        "lightcyan": #e0ffff,
        "lightgoldenrodyellow": #fafad2,
        "lightgray": #d3d3d3,
        "lightgreen": #90ee90,
        "lightgrey": #d3d3d3,
        "lightpink": #ffb6c1,
        "lightsalmon": #ffa07a,
        "lightseagreen": #20b2aa,
        "lightskyblue": #87cefa,
        "lightslategray": #778899,
        "lightslategrey": #778899,
        "lightsteelblue": #b0c4de,
        "lightyellow": #ffffe0,
        "lime": #00ff00,
        "limegreen": #32cd32,
        "linen": #faf0e6,
        "magenta": #ff00ff,
        "maroon": #800000,
        "mediumaquamarine": #66cdaa,
        "mediumblue": #0000cd,
        "mediumorchid": #ba55d3,
        "mediumpurple": #9370db,
        "mediumseagreen": #3cb371,
        "mediumslateblue": #7b68ee,
        "mediumspringgreen": #00fa9a,
        "mediumturquoise": #48d1cc,
        "mediumvioletred": #c71585,
        "midnightblue": #191970,
        "mintcream": #f5fffa,
        "mistyrose": #ffe4e1,
        "moccasin": #ffe4b5,
        "navajowhite": #ffdead,
        "navy": #000080,
        "oldlace": #fdf5e6,
        "olive": #808000,
        "olivedrab": #6b8e23,
        "orangered": #ff4500,
        "orchid": #da70d6,
        "palegoldenrod": #eee8aa,
        "palegreen": #98fb98,
        "paleturquoise": #afeeee,
        "palevioletred": #db7093,
        "papayawhip": #ffefd5,
        "peachpuff": #ffdab9,
        "peru": #cd853f,
        "plum": #dda0dd,
        "powderblue": #b0e0e6,
        "rebeccapurple": #663399,
        "rosybrown": #bc8f8f,
        "royalblue": #4169e1,
        "saddlebrown": #8b4513,
        "salmon": #fa8072,
        "sandybrown": #f4a460,
        "seagreen": #2e8b57,
        "seashell": #fff5ee,
        "sienna": #a0522d,
        "silver": #c0c0c0,
        "skyblue": #87ceeb,
        "slateblue": #6a5acd,
        "slategray": #708090,
        "slategrey": #708090,
        "snow": #fffafa,
        "springgreen": #00ff7f,
        "steelblue": #4682b4,
        "tan": #d2b48c,
        "thistle": #d8bfd8,
        "tomato": #ff6347,
        "transparent": #00000000,
        "turquoise": #40e0d0,
        "violet": #ee82ee,
        "wheat": #f5deb3,
        "white": #ffffff,
        "whitesmoke": #f5f5f5,
        "yellowgreen": #9acd32
);


@each $color, $value in $custom-colors {
    .bg-#{$color} {
      background-color: $value !important;
    }
  
    .#{$color}:hover {
      color: white !important;
    }
  
    .text-#{$color} {
      color: $value !important;
    }
  }

$theme-colors: map-merge($theme-colors, $custom-colors);

@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

y me resulta en este error:

```
--------------------
Change Detected...
styles.scss
--------------------
Compilation Error
Error: argument `$color` of `red($color)` must be a color
        on line 185 of sass/d:\Desarrollos\Personales\custom BS5\node_modules\bootstrap\scss\_functions.scss, in function `red`
        from line 185 of sass/d:\Desarrollos\Personales\custom BS5\node_modules\bootstrap\scss\_functions.scss, in function `luminance`
        from line 174 of sass/d:\Desarrollos\Personales\custom BS5\node_modules\bootstrap\scss\_functions.scss, in function `contrast-ratio`
        from line 159 of sass/d:\Desarrollos\Personales\custom BS5\node_modules\bootstrap\scss\_functions.scss, in function `color-contrast`
        from line 10 of sass/d:\Desarrollos\Personales\custom BS5\node_modules\bootstrap\scss\mixins\_buttons.scss, in mixin `button-variant`
        from line 61 of sass/d:\Desarrollos\Personales\custom BS5\node_modules\bootstrap\scss\_buttons.scss
        from line 24 of sass/d:\Desarrollos\Personales\custom BS5\node_modules\bootstrap\scss\bootstrap.scss
        from line 165 of sass/d:\Desarrollos\Personales\custom BS5\styles.scss
>>     "r": red($color),

   ---------^

--------------------
Watching...
--------------------
```

***UPDATE***

He intentado declarando las variables de los colores

```
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";

$rc-red: #DA291C;
$rc-wine: #A50034;
$rc-blue: #002554;
$rc-gold: #FFB200;
$rc-silver: #808080;
$rc-skyblue: #00B0F0;


$aliceblue:#F0F8FF;
$antiquewhite:#FAEBD7;
$aqua:#00FFFF;
$aquamarine:#7FFFD4;
$azure:#F0FFFF;
$beige:#F5F5DC;
$bisque:#FFE4C4;
$blanchedalmond:#FFEBCD;
$blueviolet:#8A2BE2;
$brown:#A52A2A;
$burlywood:#DEB887;
$cadetblue:#5F9EA0;
$chartreuse:#7FFF00;
$chocolate:#D2691E;
$coral:#FF7F50;
$cornflowerblue:#6495ED;
$cornsilk:#FFF8DC;
$crimson:#DC143C;
$darkblue:#00008B;
$darkcyan:#008B8B;
$darkgoldenrod:#B8860B;
$darkgray:#A9A9A9;
$darkgreen:#006400;
$darkgrey:#A9A9A9;
$darkkhaki:#BDB76B;
$darkmagenta:#8B008B;
$darkolivegreen:#556B2F;
$darkorange:#FF8C00;
$darkorchid:#9932CC;
$darkred:#8B0000;
$darksalmon:#E9967A;
$darkseagreen:#8FBC8F;
$darkslateblue:#483D8B;
$darkslategray:#2F4F4F;
$darkslategrey:#2F4F4F;
$darkturquoise:#00CED1;
$darkviolet:#9400D3;
$deeppink:#FF1493;
$deepskyblue:#00BFFF;
$dimgray:#696969;
$dimgrey:#696969;
$dodgerblue:#1E90FF;
$firebrick:#B22222;
$floralwhite:#FFFAF0;
$forestgreen:#228B22;
$fuchsia:#FF00FF;
$gainsboro:#DCDCDC;
$ghostwhite:#F8F8FF;
$gold:#FFD700;
$goldenrod:#DAA520;
$greenyellow:#ADFF2F;
$grey:#808080;
$honeydew:#F0FFF0;
$hotpink:#FF69B4;
$indianred:#CD5C5C;
$ivory:#FFFFF0;
$khaki:#F0E68C;
$lavender:#E6E6FA;
$lavenderblush:#FFF0F5;
$lawngreen:#7CFC00;
$lemonchiffon:#FFFACD;
$lightblue:#ADD8E6;
$lightcoral:#F08080;
$lightcyan:#E0FFFF;
$lightgoldenrodyellow:#FAFAD2;
$lightgray:#D3D3D3;
$lightgreen:#90EE90;
$lightgrey:#D3D3D3;
$lightpink:#FFB6C1;
$lightsalmon:#FFA07A;
$lightseagreen:#20B2AA;
$lightskyblue:#87CEFA;
$lightslategray:#778899;
$lightslategrey:#778899;
$lightsteelblue:#B0C4DE;
$lightyellow:#FFFFE0;
$lime:#00FF00;
$limegreen:#32CD32;
$linen:#FAF0E6;
$magenta:#FF00FF;
$maroon:#800000;
$mediumaquamarine:#66CDAA;
$mediumblue:#0000CD;
$mediumorchid:#BA55D3;
$mediumpurple:#9370DB;
$mediumseagreen:#3CB371;
$mediumslateblue:#7B68EE;
$mediumspringgreen:#00FA9A;
$mediumturquoise:#48D1CC;
$mediumvioletred:#C71585;
$midnightblue:#191970;
$mintcream:#F5FFFA;
$mistyrose:#FFE4E1;
$moccasin:#FFE4B5;
$navajowhite:#FFDEAD;
$navy:#000080;
$oldlace:#FDF5E6;
$olive:#808000;
$olivedrab:#6B8E23;
$orangered:#FF4500;
$orchid:#DA70D6;
$palegoldenrod:#EEE8AA;
$palegreen:#98FB98;
$paleturquoise:#AFEEEE;
$palevioletred:#DB7093;
$papayawhip:#FFEFD5;
$peachpuff:#FFDAB9;
$peru:#CD853F;
$plum:#DDA0DD;
$powderblue:#B0E0E6;
$rebeccapurple:#663399;
$rosybrown:#BC8F8F;
$royalblue:#4169E1;
$saddlebrown:#8B4513;
$salmon:#FA8072;
$sandybrown:#F4A460;
$seagreen:#2E8B57;
$seashell:#FFF5EE;
$sienna:#A0522D;
$silver:#C0C0C0;
$skyblue:#87CEEB;
$slateblue:#6A5ACD;
$slategray:#708090;
$slategrey:#708090;
$snow:#FFFAFA;
$springgreen:#00FF7F;
$steelblue:#4682B4;
$tan:#D2B48C;
$thistle:#D8BFD8;
$tomato:#FF6347;
$transparent:#00000000;
$turquoise:#40E0D0;
$violet:#EE82EE;
$wheat:#F5DEB3;
$white:#FFFFFF;
$whitesmoke:#F5F5F5;
$yellowgreen:#9ACD32;


$custom-colors: (
  "rc-red": $rc-red,
  "rc-wine": $rc-wine,
  "rc-blue": $rc-blue,
  "rc-gold": $rc-gold,
  "rc-silver": $rc-silver,
  "rc-skyblue": $rc-skyblue,
  "aliceblue": $aliceblue, 
  "antiquewhite": $antiquewhite, 
  "aqua": $aqua, 
  "aquamarine": $aquamarine, 
  "azure": $azure, 
  "beige": $beige, 
  "bisque": $bisque, 
  "blanchedalmond": $blanchedalmond, 
  "blueviolet": $blueviolet, 
  "brown": $brown, 
  "burlywood": $burlywood, 
  "cadetblue": $cadetblue, 
  "chartreuse": $chartreuse, 
  "chocolate": $chocolate, 
  "coral": $coral, 
  "cornflowerblue": $cornflowerblue, 
  "cornsilk": $cornsilk, 
  "crimson": $crimson, 
  "darkblue": $darkblue, 
  "darkcyan": $darkcyan, 
  "darkgoldenrod": $darkgoldenrod, 
  "darkgray": $darkgray, 
  "darkgreen": $darkgreen, 
  "darkgrey": $darkgrey, 
  "darkkhaki": $darkkhaki, 
  "darkmagenta": $darkmagenta, 
  "darkolivegreen": $darkolivegreen, 
  "darkorange": $darkorange, 
  "darkorchid": $darkorchid, 
  "darkred": $darkred, 
  "darksalmon": $darksalmon, 
  "darkseagreen": $darkseagreen, 
  "darkslateblue": $darkslateblue, 
  "darkslategray": $darkslategray, 
  "darkslategrey": $darkslategrey, 
  "darkturquoise": $darkturquoise, 
  "darkviolet": $darkviolet, 
  "deeppink": $deeppink, 
  "deepskyblue": $deepskyblue, 
  "dimgray": $dimgray, 
  "dimgrey": $dimgrey, 
  "dodgerblue": $dodgerblue, 
  "firebrick": $firebrick, 
  "floralwhite": $floralwhite, 
  "forestgreen": $forestgreen, 
  "fuchsia": $fuchsia, 
  "gainsboro": $gainsboro, 
  "ghostwhite": $ghostwhite, 
  "gold": $gold, 
  "goldenrod": $goldenrod, 
  "greenyellow": $greenyellow, 
  "grey": $grey, 
  "honeydew": $honeydew, 
  "hotpink": $hotpink, 
  "indianred": $indianred, 
  "ivory": $ivory, 
  "khaki": $khaki, 
  "lavender": $lavender, 
  "lavenderblush": $lavenderblush, 
  "lawngreen": $lawngreen, 
  "lemonchiffon": $lemonchiffon, 
  "lightblue": $lightblue, 
  "lightcoral": $lightcoral, 
  "lightcyan": $lightcyan, 
  "lightgoldenrodyellow": $lightgoldenrodyellow, 
  "lightgray": $lightgray, 
  "lightgreen": $lightgreen, 
  "lightgrey": $lightgrey, 
  "lightpink": $lightpink, 
  "lightsalmon": $lightsalmon, 
  "lightseagreen": $lightseagreen, 
  "lightskyblue": $lightskyblue, 
  "lightslategray": $lightslategray, 
  "lightslategrey": $lightslategrey, 
  "lightsteelblue": $lightsteelblue, 
  "lightyellow": $lightyellow, 
  "lime": $lime, 
  "limegreen": $limegreen, 
  "linen": $linen, 
  "magenta": $magenta, 
  "maroon": $maroon, 
  "mediumaquamarine": $mediumaquamarine, 
  "mediumblue": $mediumblue, 
  "mediumorchid": $mediumorchid, 
  "mediumpurple": $mediumpurple, 
  "mediumseagreen": $mediumseagreen, 
  "mediumslateblue": $mediumslateblue, 
  "mediumspringgreen": $mediumspringgreen, 
  "mediumturquoise": $mediumturquoise, 
  "mediumvioletred": $mediumvioletred, 
  "midnightblue": $midnightblue, 
  "mintcream": $mintcream, 
  "mistyrose": $mistyrose, 
  "moccasin": $moccasin, 
  "navajowhite": $navajowhite, 
  "navy": $navy, 
  "oldlace": $oldlace, 
  "olive": $olive, 
  "olivedrab": $olivedrab, 
  "orangered": $orangered, 
  "orchid": $orchid, 
  "palegoldenrod": $palegoldenrod, 
  "palegreen": $palegreen, 
  "paleturquoise": $paleturquoise, 
  "palevioletred": $palevioletred, 
  "papayawhip": $papayawhip, 
  "peachpuff": $peachpuff, 
  "peru": $peru, 
  "plum": $plum, 
  "powderblue": $powderblue, 
  "rebeccapurple": $rebeccapurple, 
  "rosybrown": $rosybrown, 
  "royalblue": $royalblue, 
  "saddlebrown": $saddlebrown, 
  "salmon": $salmon, 
  "sandybrown": $sandybrown, 
  "seagreen": $seagreen, 
  "seashell": $seashell, 
  "sienna": $sienna, 
  "silver": $silver, 
  "skyblue": $skyblue, 
  "slateblue": $slateblue, 
  "slategray": $slategray, 
  "slategrey": $slategrey, 
  "snow": $snow, 
  "springgreen": $springgreen, 
  "steelblue": $steelblue, 
  "tan": $tan, 
  "thistle": $thistle, 
  "tomato": $tomato, 
  "transparent": $transparent, 
  "turquoise": $turquoise, 
  "violet": $violet, 
  "wheat": $wheat, 
  "white": $white, 
  "whitesmoke": $whitesmoke, 
  "yellowgreen": $yellowgreen
);

@each $color, $value in $custom-colors {
  .bg-#{$color} {
    background-color: $value !important;
  }

  .text-#{$color} {
    color: $value !important;
  }

}

$theme-colors: map-merge($theme-colors, $custom-colors);

@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

**No logro dar con el error: no he tocado nada de lo que sale en los errores; incluso si quito la paleta de colores extendida el error deja de aparecer.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es muy importante que al añadir elementos a Bootstrap o variables no sobre escriban ninguna en mi caso estoy creando el color white en la paleta custom que al compilar choca con la paleta original; aunque el error no lo describe este este es uno de los problemas; el otro problema que detecte es que el script de compilación de variables de Bootstrap no admite el color de transparencia #00000000 este es otro error que revienta la compilación del scss a css.